# Python how to debug SIGBUS / SIGILL error?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, sigbus

I have a very long-running python script, which synchronises data across different systems. It does a lot of data retrieval, data transformation, HTTP requests, and all of that partially multithreaded.

The script sometimes produces SIGBUS / SIGILL errors and I have no clue how to handle them properly.

The program works on roughly 500 items in a threaded way. Each item is a dictionary like this.

```
def processing(item):
    reduced_df = item['streets']
    reduced_df = reduced_df[reduced_df['city'] == item['city_country']['city']].copy()
    do stuff with reduced_df

preped_streets # this is the main_data_frame

items = [{
    'city_country': comb,
    'language': language,
    'streets': preped_streets
} for comb in city_country_combinations for language in ['en','de',...]]

with pool.ThreadPool(processes=32) as pool:
   pool.map(processing, items)
```

Now I have never encountered SIGBUS or SIGILL before, but after doing some reading I figured something this severe has got to do with the fact that I am threading here and threads are trying to access something that another thread destroyed?

Comment: These errors are bugs in the Python interpreter or the libraries, not something in your code.

Comment: How big are the list of languages and `city_country_combinations`? This could be due to running out of memory, although I'd expect Python to report that more sensibly.

Comment: language is a 2 letter string, comb is a 2 element dictionary {city:x,country:y}, preped_streets is large. Data frame with 5000 rows and 10 columns. But I think this is passed by reference, no?

Comment: I meant how many elements are there in each. The length of `items` will be `len(city_country_combinations) * len(['en','de',...])`

Comment: Ohhh, well in total it’s roughly 500 items, 100 city_country_comb and 5 languages

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem at all. I was worried that it was millions.